# How do the default themes reference style.css?

Tags: theme-development, css, headers

I was expecting to see `get_stylesheet_uri()` called somewhere in the default header.php file for the default themes (2012-14), but anything like it is missing, which has me wondering how the reference is added.

The default theme headers have something like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Looking at the source for the themes, shows a proper link to the stylesheet in the header, so, how does it get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stylesheet is [registered](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) and [enqueued](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) by [a function called `twentyfourteen_scripts()` in the theme's `functions.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php#L225). 
Callbacks hooked into the style loader/dependency system will be [`echo`ed on the `wp_head` action](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L198) in the [`wp_head()` function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1634).

Which, by the way, is how you should be loading your own stylesheets. There is a similar system for scripts.